# NoMethodError at /todo_lists undefined method `save' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am making an app with a todo list and I recently tried to add the ability to build out the todo lists from the user.

I ran into a problem when I changed the following lines.

```
def new
  @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build
end

def create
    @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists(todo_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I was using the following code.

```
def new
  @todo_list = TodoList.new
end

def create
    @todo_list = TodoList.new(todo_list_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have added a user id to the todo items by creating a new migration and migrated the data base and created an association to the user for the posts. Not really sure what's going wrong but any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists(todo_list_params)
```

into this:

```
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build(todo_list_params)
```